# jQuery Validate error for jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-11

I'm using jquery validate using this scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

My form work well in Chrome/Firefox but in IE 11 it ignores the jquery validate.

Using the debugger to break in the exceptions ,it gets error:
[image]

Comment: Construct a working demo that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Are you using valid HTML?  A valid `doctype`? In other words, if your HTML is invalid, you are forcing Explorer into Compatibility Mode, where these kinds of errors are common.

Comment: @sparky i do have for IE 'display intranet sites in compatibility view' check because we have to for us, and <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: Then that's your whole problem.  Compatibility Mode is only the fallback for older code that may not work in a newer browser.

Comment: I just got it to work when unchecking the 'display intranet sites in compatibility view' is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Yes, don't force Compatibility Mode.

Comment: duh , great got it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's comment:

> i do have for IE 'display intranet sites in compatibility view' check because we have to for us, and `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Use valid HTML and do not force the site into "Compatibility Mode".  Compatibility Mode was only designed as a fallback to help older code work in newer versions of Explorer.